# Show only the div containing the current hour

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list containing a schedule and I want to show only the div that contains the current hour...I tried something like this:

```
<div class="sch">17:20 BurnIT</div>
<div class="sch">18:00 AQA</div>
<div class="sch">19:25 Dynamic Stretch</div>
<div class="sch">20:50 HydroRider</div>

var d = new Date();
var h = (d.getHours());

$(".sch").each(function () {
    var time = $(this).html().substr(0, 2)
    if (time === h) {
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    };
});
```

Comment: Either don't use ===, since `time` will be a string but h will be an int; or cast the string using `parseInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to hide the particular element, also you can use **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** with Boolean to show and hide. Use `==` instead of `===` to avoid type mismatch

```js
var d = new Date();
var h = (d.getHours());
$(".sch").each(function() {
  var time = $(this).html().substr(0, 2)
  $(this).toggle(time == h)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sch">17:20 BurnIT</div>
<div class="sch">18:00 AQA</div>
<div class="sch">19:25 Dynamic Stretch</div>
<div class="sch">22:50 HydroRider</div>
```

Comment: I just figured out what I was doing wrong...cause I already tried with 'this' and it didn't work for me...that was cause i used 3 equal signs instead of two...

Comment: Upvoted and will accept as soon as I can :) Thanks for helping me figure out what I was doing wrong :)